# Why is my very large file upload "Stalled" in Chrome?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer, multer-s3

I have built a Node/Express server behind Nginx & a javascript webapp to upload files. The webapp uses `multer` for uploads. I have adjusted Nginx to accept up to 10GB files.

When I attempt to send a 4GB file, Chrome craps itself with a "stalled" message in the Timing tab. There is no message about the error at `/var/logs/nginx/error.log`

Is there some practical limit to file upload using `multer` (`multer-s3`)? What strategy can I use for uploading large files like this? I have read about 'chunking' in answers from 2012, but surely this is a thoroughly solved problem.

Thank you

Comment: are you saying that it works fine on other browsers?

Comment: nope. i'll try other browsers and report back